# Ignoring TIMESTAMPDIFF between specific times

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible you count a sum in minutes but not between a certain time say between 2300 and 0700

```
SELECT SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, open_time, close_time)) 
FROM requests;
```

The code I have above counts the time in minutes but does also counts overnight this is what I want to avoid.

Thanks for your help I am not an SQL Professional at all!

Comment: MySQL doesn't provide a builtin function to return this result.

Comment: Thanks Spencer can you recommend a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It should work for periods spanning more than one night as well.

```
SELECT SUM( TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, open_time, close_time) - (DATEDIFF(close_time, open_time) * 480))
FROM requests;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all cases. As one trivial example: `2016-02-16 22:00` to `2016-02-17 08:30` should return 150. The expression in this answer will return -170.

Comment: You're correct. But only due to sloppy math on my part. That's what I get for commenting so late at night. Instead of subtracting 800, subtract 480 (i.e. 60 mins per hour of non-work time). I've made the necessary correction.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll tinker around later

Comment: Even with the change, in some corner cases, this expression doesn't return a reasonable value. For example: for values of open_time and close_time of `2016-02-16 22:00` and `2016-02-17 01:10`, the (edited) expression returns **-290** rather than **60**.  (I think this answer is incomplete without giving a note of the values for open_time and close_time this expression works for.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any builtin function that will return the specified result. And I don't know of any easy expression that will handle all of the possible cases.

One alternative would be to define a function (MySQL stored program) that will calculate that difference.

As an example, if we entirely ignore any "seconds" portion of the datetime/timestamps, and work with whole minutes, something like this:

NOTE: this is *not* fully tested. (Consider handling of open/close that span a daylight savings time change. This might work just fine, but it hasn't been tested. This just serves as a demonstration of a possible approach.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `worktimeminutes`(open_time DATETIME, close_time DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
   DECLARE tot_minutes INT;
   DECLARE wrk_clock   DATETIME;
   DECLARE nxt_2300    DATETIME;

   SET tot_minutes := 0;
   SET wrk_clock   := open_time;

   -- exit early if either argument NULL
   IF open_time IS NULL OR close_time IS NULL THEN
      RETURN NULL;
   END IF;

   -- exit early if open_time time is on or after close_time
   IF open_time >= close_time THEN
      RETURN 0;
   END IF;

   myloop: LOOP

      -- if after 11PM, skip clock forward to 7AM
      IF DATE_FORMAT(wrk_clock,'%H%i') >= '2300' THEN
         SET wrk_clock := DATE_FORMAT(wrk_clock,'%Y-%m-%d 07:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
      END IF;
      SET nxt_2300 := DATE_FORMAT(wrk_clock,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 23 HOUR;

      -- have we reached close_time yet?
      IF wrk_clock >= close_time THEN
         LEAVE myloop;
      END IF;

      IF close_time < nxt_2300 THEN
         SET tot_minutes := tot_minutes + TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,wrk_clock,close_time);
      ELSE
         SET tot_minutes := tot_minutes + TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,wrk_clock,nxt_2300);
      END IF;

      SET wrk_clock := nxt_2300;

   END LOOP myloop;

   RETURN tot_minutes;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

With the function defined in MySQL, we can run a few simple test cases. We can reference the function in a SELECT statement just like a builtin function.

```
SELECT t.open_time
     , t.close_time
     , worktimeminutes(t.open_time,t.close_time)  AS worktimeminutes
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t.open_time,t.close_time) AS tsdiff
  FROM ( SELECT NULL AS open_time, NULL AS close_time
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 11:00', '2016-02-16 21:00'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 21:00', '2016-02-16 23:15'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 22:00', '2016-02-17 01:10'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 23:15', '2016-02-17 01:12'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 22:00', '2016-02-17 08:30'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 23:30', '2016-02-17 08:30'
         UNION ALL SELECT '2016-02-16 23:30', '2016-02-18 08:30'
    ) t
```

returns:

```
open_time         close_time        worktimeminutes  tsdiff  
----------------  ----------------  ---------------  --------
(NULL)            (NULL)                     (NULL)    (NULL)
2016-02-16 11:00  2016-02-16 21:00              600       600
2016-02-16 21:00  2016-02-16 23:15              120       135
2016-02-16 22:00  2016-02-17 01:10               60       190
2016-02-16 23:15  2016-02-17 01:12                0       117
2016-02-16 22:00  2016-02-17 08:30              150       630
2016-02-16 23:30  2016-02-17 08:30               90       540
2016-02-16 23:30  2016-02-18 08:30             1050      1980
```

Comment: Thank you for putting this together I'll have a look and see if this is plausible.

Comment: @DJones: I'd recommend that whatever expression you use to calculate the difference in minutes not counting overnight, that you fully test it, with a reasonable set of values of `open_time` and `close_time`, including times within the overnight hours, spanning multiple days, and even test the oddball case where close_time is before open_time.  (You don't need to be a SQL Professional to be able to run some tests.)

Comment: Thanks Spencer for the consideration